# How to send data in FormData to api?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, form-data, react-hook-form

I want to send the data to the Api as **FormData**
I use react **react-hook-form** This is what I have:

```
const submitForm = (data) => {
    console.log(data)==>{Title:"test" ,Countent:"countent"} 
    service.uploadFile(data, (status, result) => {
      if (result.Success) {
        props.notifySuccess(result.Message);
      } else {
        props.notifyError(result.Message);
      }
    });
  };
```

How do I send data as FormData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const submitForm = (data) => {
     const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(data).forEach((ele) => formData.append(ele, data[ele]))
    service.uploadFile(formData, (status, result) => {
      if (result.Success) {
        props.notifySuccess(result.Message);
      } else {
        props.notifyError(result.Message);
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: This is how it is arranged{Title:"jjj" ,content:(binary)}, how can I reverse it?like this:{,content:(binary) ,Title:"jjj" }